# Wrong Solution?

Tags: statistics

So I got this solution from the web cause my textbook doesn't come with steps, is the second summation wrong though? But the final answer is correct.

[image]

For $n=0$, $P(X=2^0+1) = P(X=2)$

$2\ne odd$

Comment: The final answer is correct. Perhaps steer clear of the summation formatting and write out the probabilities as a list for the first few. This may make things easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it carefully! 
The book doesn't state $X = 2^n + 1$ but $X=2n+1$.
Otherwise the third equality sign is false and you wouldn't get e.g. $X=7$ because there is no $n\in \Bbb N$ s.t. $2^n + 1 = 7$

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! The formatting was so messed up.